how to fix VS Code search working inappropriate


In VScode am trying to search in all files and replace the copyright year from 2023 to 2025 but the search is not finding correct characters. And so the replace is not working as intended. instead changing from 1995, 2023 to 1995, 2025 it changes to 19, 202523. This occurs in few instances and in few files its working properly(irrespective of file types). My file types generally are .c, .cpp, .h, .hpp, .vcproj
my system is : Macbook pro 16 with M3. So is it a bug in mac vscode? or is there a way to fix this?

note: cannot repro on ubuntu 24.04 with VS Code 1.94.2
